# Adding custom AnnotationView in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using following code to make custom AnnotationView.

My `CustomPointAnnotation` is a subclass of `MKPointAnnotation` with a setter/getter of `Player`

```
   -(void) showMarkers
    {
        [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < [self.playersArray count];  i ++)
        {
            Players *player = [self.playersArray objectAtIndex:i];

            CustomPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[CustomPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            [annotationPoint setPlayer:player];

            if ([player.name isEqualToString:self.name.text])
            {
                NSLog(@"%@ , %@" , player.name,self.name.text);
                annotationPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([player.latitude doubleValue]+.1, [player.longitude doubleValue]+.1);
                  [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@ , %@" , player.name,self.name.text);
                annotationPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([player.latitude doubleValue], [player.longitude doubleValue]);
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
            }
         }
        [self.mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    }

    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
    {
      //  self.mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
        myLocation = userLocation;
    }

    -(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
        if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"] )
        {
               return nil;
        }


        CustomAnnotationView *annView = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"players"];
        CustomPointAnnotation *ptAnnotation = (CustomPointAnnotation *) annotation;
        [annView setPlayer:ptAnnotation.player];

        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"];
        annView.enabled = YES;
        [annView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        return annView;

    }
```

The problem comes at `[annView setPlayer:ptAnnotation.player]; Unrecognized selector sent to instance`
I am adding CustomPointAnnotation so it should convert it back. How can i solve this issue

Comment: The custom class should be an NSObject class and should conform to <MKAnnotation>

Comment: @RohanKapur I tried with this but it started giving me errors at     annotationPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([player.latitude doubleValue]+.1, [player.longitude doubleValue]+.1);
Can you explain how to make one

Comment: CustomPointAnnotation setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: OK, I have provided an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Im not sure how you declared the custom class, but it goes like this:

.h:

```
@interface CustomPointAnnotation: NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

}

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate coordinate;
// Other properties like title, subtitle, etc.
```

.m

```
@implementation CustomPointAnnotation 

@synthesize coordinate; // and other properties
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface CustomPointAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{

    Player *player;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) Player *player;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate coordinate;
```

Do not subclass MKAnnotation istead confirm to MKAnnotation protocal.

```
@interface CustomAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
{


}
```

no need to set the player. when you need to access the player object access it using the annotation in CustomAnnotationView.

```
CustomPointAnnotation *annotation=self.annotation;
annotation.player;
```